# Is there a way I can test/verify my answers to limit computations?

Tags: calculus, limits

As a student, for a long time I've relied on different ways to "verify" my answers during execises.

When solving equations, you could plug in your answer into the variables and easily determine if your answer is potentially correct or not.

When working with lines, vectors and planes, I had to find things like intersection points, which were easily verifiable by also plugging in the values (after all they were pretty much equations too).

And today I am working with limits. For example, things like 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 3x}{\sin 7x}$$

Where my answer would be

$$\frac{3}{7}$$

Is there a way to efficiently test my answers to limit exercises?

Comment: http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/calculus/limit-calculator.php

Comment: @RaziehNoori ah yes, but is there a way to verify this on paper? Without tools?

Comment: for this one L'Hôpital's rule  is  the best.

Comment: You mean something other than plugging in a very small value of $ x $ and using your calculator? Maybe you can find different ways to look at the limit and check that they give the same answer. In this case, you can use the approximation $\sin z \approx z $ (when $ z $ is small).

Comment: I think the best you can come up with here is probably coming up with the same answer using two different methods, but this also is somewhat non-trivial since in this case you will end up in using different flavors of l'Hospital's rule. A "backward" test would be interresting to see if there's any feasible such.

Comment: If you have a calculator handy, then xpmrz's answer below is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

The limit of $\lim_{x\to m}f(x)=L$ means as x approaches m, f(x) approaches L. T
If you need to verify your answer for limit at a point m, just plug some / set of  values that is near m or approach m to the equation and see if it converges to your limit (For your example m=0, so try x=0.00001 and see if f(x) is near 3/7  ). If it is the case, then you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to evaluate this limit,
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(7x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(3x)(7x)\sin(3x)}{(3x)(7x)\sin(7x)}$$
$$=\frac37\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\right)\left(\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{7x}{\sin(7x)}\right)=\frac37$$
Another way would be to show that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(7x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(7x)}=\frac37$$
Does one answer validate the other answer? **Nope**. The steps taken to arrive at the answer is what truly validates the answer.

Comment: OP didn't ask how to solve this particular limit.  (S)he asked how to verify the solution to limits in general.